# How to make trailing / in url optional Django

Tags: django

I have registered my urls in django and noticed that the trailing / is not optional, meaning that if I register like so:

```
path('home', homepage),
```

Then I can't go to `home/`

How do I allow both? Do I have to register both for each url? Thanks!!

Comment: define `path('home/', homepage)` and set the `APPEND_SLASH` setting to `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the path with a trailing slash:

```
path('home/', homepage),
```

If you set the [**`APPEND_SLASH`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#append-slash) to `True` (it is by *default* `True`, so there is no need to explicitly specify it), then it will add a slash and try the paths again if the path without the slash did not yield any results.

As specified in the documentation:

> When set to `True`, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an **HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended**. Note that the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be lost.

As is specified, for POST requests however, this will not work. POST requests are however normally made by a form, where th action is specified by the developer of the website. So it is the responsibility of the developer to ensure that the paths are properly written in the HTML forms. You can make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for that.

Comment: I was just thinking -> how would I make it default to not use the slash? So test.com/test/ would redirect to test.com/test ??